# Facebook ads are getting created with bigger RHS ad format

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am creating right hand side (RHS) ad and specifying 100x72 in image_crop field through API. If the image is big enough in dimension, it is getting created in the new RHS format.

Also, the crop specification I am giving is not been respected. Either the ads getting cropped from middle or the full image is taken as part of creative. How do I stop from creating the ads in new RHS format and why is the image_crop configuration not being reflected in the ad creative.

Answer (score 1):

In the new creative model, the right hand side will require you to have the larger image format. Please see the [July breaking change announcement](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/ads-api-changes-2014-07-02).

To specify the correct `image_crop` you must specify the configuration for the [correct ratio](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/image-crops/#cropkeys):

```
{
   "191x100": [ [100, 10], [433, 184] ],
   "100x72": [ [160, 20], [371, 172] ]
}
```